# ARKit How can I know root node is initialized

Tags: arkit

[image: please click to see pic]

above x, y, z is root node.

1. I want to know when root node is shown
2. how to show/hide root node on screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ever 'show the node', but you can attach objects to the node and visualise those, as you have done (with the lines).

If you want to see the actual point that the node is at, you can attach a `SCNSphere` (or any `geometry`).

```
let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(0.02))
sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.magenta

var node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
```

As an aside, you can make the node visible / invisible using `node.isHidden = true` etc. This will hide the node, any attached geometry, and all of its children nodes.